# Local Javascript and CDN precedence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jquery from new boston video tutorials and have 2 questions asked below. Aim is to hide a paragraph when user clicks on it. But first, this is what I did to hide a paragraph on click.

hide.js looks like this

```
$('#paragraph').click(
function() {
    $('#paragraph').hide();
}
);
```

1. CDN followed by local JS in Body - Works
   [image]
2. Local JS followed by CDN in Body - Does not Work
   [image]
3. Local JS followed by CDN in Head - Does not Work
   [image]
4. CDN followed by local JS in Head - Does not Work
   [image]

Q1. Seeing the cases, can we confidently say that scripts declared in HEAD section will never work?

Q2. Can someone please explain these different behaviors?

Comment: So you're loading "hide.js" via  a CDN? What is "local js" then?

Comment: @ChrisHardie local js is the one defined above. I will be using CDN for some other function.

Comment: local JS = hide.js Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this problem, you have to understand how javascript gets included on the page from external resources and how the browser builds the dom.

When you include two script tags:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

The first is downloaded and executed, then the second is downloaded and executed. If in the first script a property is defined, for example, `window.hello`, you can access it in the second script because the second script gets downloaded and executed after the first has finished. If the scripts were in the other order, the property would not be available yet.

As far as including your code in the head vs in the body, you have to think about when the code executes relative to the browser parsing the html and creating the DOM. The browser reads the html top to bottom, therefore, when it reaches your script tag in the head, the body node doesn't even exist yet. This is why your code doesn't work in the head. To make it work in the head, you must somehow tell your code to *wait until the element exists*. The most common way to solve this is with the DOMContentLoaded event, which you can bind to with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // my code here
});
```

You could also use the window load event.

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
    // my code here
})
```

It's better to use DOMContentLoaded unless your code needs to get the width or height of an element because it will happen sooner.

A third option would be to use event delegation, but it really doesn't fit will with your usecase.

```
$(document).on('click','#paragraph',function() {
    $('#paragraph').hide();
});
```

It's typically a better idea to have your javascript before the closing body tag, however it's often not very easy to do it that way with many MVC and CMS systems.

Answer (score 1):

If `hide.js` uses jQuery, then yes, you need to load `jquery.min.js` first. That explains (2) and (3).

The problem with (4) is that you need to wrap your code in a [`document.ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) block. Since the `<body>` is located after the `<head>`, `#paragraph` doesn't exist at the time `hide.js` is run.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

So two things are happening.  Your code has to be loaded after the jQuery code is loaded because it leverages jQuery to hide your paragraph.

Secondly your code will have to be loaded after the DOM is loaded so that it can access your paragraph element.

That is why number 1 works and none of the others do.  You have loaded it after the tag you want to affect and jQuery is loaded before your script.

You can also wrap your script in `$(document).ready(function() {})` to make sure that the DOM is loaded before your script runs.  This will let you put the script in the head, but you'll still have to load jQuery first.

So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /// your script here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two potential problems.

1. The code within `hide.js` uses jQuery functions. Those functions must be defined when the code tries to use them. If you include `hide.js` before jQuery, then, at the point in time that the browser tries to execute `hide.js` it will not have (yet) loaded jQuery, so the jQuery functions won't be defined. Thus: you must include jQuery **before** you  include `hide.js`.
2. The code within `hide.js` references content in the web page. The browser must have loaded the page (and parsed it) in order to find that content. If you include `hide.js` in the `<head>` tag, it is guaranteed that that content won't be available when `hide.js` executes. (So the answer to Q1 is "Yes". However, simply moving the scripts to the bottom of the page isn't guaranteed to work either. Note that the browser must have loaded **and parsed** the page before it can find the content. By moving the scripts to the bottom, you will have ensured that the page is loaded. But you won't have guaranteed that the page has been parsed. In the simple example above, even the slowest browser will have likely parsed the page. That's why it appears to work. To be really safe, however, you should not execute `hide.js` until you're certain that the page has been parsed by the browser. You can use jQuery to tell you when that has occurred:

   $(function(){
       $('#paragraph').click(
           function() {
               $('#para graph').hide();
           }
       );
   });

Answer (score 0):

First, use $(document).ready():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#paragraph').click(function() {
    $('#paragraph').hide();
  });
});
```

Put Jquery local or CDN  *before* your custom script.

```
<script src="myjQueryCDNorLocal.js"></scritpt>
<script src="myCustomScripts.js"></scritpt>
```